# save/export PGAdmin server list configuration settings

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, configuration

I have a ton of configured connections listed in the Server Groups, is there a way I can save this? not just save the passwords but the Server Group Settings

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464396/pgadmin-sharing-db-connection-definitions

Answer (score 29):

Under **Windows**, **pgAdmin4** stores the server list in the users directory in a SQLLite 3 format. Here:

`%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin\pgadmin4.db`

Comment: It's so insanely frustrating how devs never include folders like this in their uninstallation process.

Answer (score 16):

Under Windows this information is stored in the Registry under the key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\pgAdmin III
```

In Linux systems I would expect some file in the user home directory.

Answer (score 14):

In Ubuntu 13.10 pgAdmin stores configuration in user's home directory:

```
/home/<<username>>/.pgadmin3
or shorter
~/.pgadmin3
```

Note that this file is hidden, so you may need to enable some kind of "Show hidden files" option in your file manager.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into a similar issue where I was on OSX and now have a windows computer.  I don't want to have to re-enter all of the connection entries.   I found out that on OSX the PGADMIN III servers list is located in your home user directory inside the file "pgadmin3 Preferences":

```
vim ~/Library/Preferences/pgadmin3\ Preferences
```

Now it doesn't seem like there is an easy way to import this into a non-OSX version, however at least I should be able to copy/paste most of it into the new PGADMIN III application.

Answer (score 4):

I've the same issue and solve it in this way, using this [doc](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/import_export_servers.html#importing-servers)

1. Export

   ```
   /path/to/python /path/to/setup.py --dump-servers /path/to/pg4_cnx.json
   ```

Output message : Configuration for x servers dumped to /path/to/pg4_cnx.json.

2. Import

   ```
   /path/to/python /path/to/setup.py --load-servers /path/to/pg4_cnx.json
   ```

Output message : Added n Server Group(s) and x Server(s).

Under Windows (7|10), you can find "python.exe" & "setup.py" in this sub-dirs of your PgAdmin4 install :
\pgAdmin 4\venv\Scripts\python.exe
\pgAdmin 4\web\setup.py

Hope this help you

Comment: Doesn't seem to work anymore, or at least not on windows. I had to install ~10 flask modules with pip to get it to run, then even after it ran, I got a sqlachemy type error exception.
```The argument passed to Dialect.has_table() should be a <class 'sqlalchemy.engine.base.Connection'>, got <class 'sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine'>. Additionally, the Dialect.has_table() method is for internal dialect use only; please use ``inspect(some_engine).has_table(<tablename>>)`` for public API use.```

Comment: @BrennenSprimont Do you use the python version that ships with pgAdmin? Make sure to use `C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\python.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

This is works for me in Windows 11

```
C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6>python\python.exe web\setup.py --dump-servers C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\pgadmin_connections.json
```

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6>python\python.exe web\setup.py --dump-servers C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\pgadmin_connections.json
```

Above command is correct and event it works for v5 ->

```
C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v5>python\python.exe web\setup.py --dump-servers C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\pgadmin_connections.json
```

But to get them worked, need to make some changes as mentioned in below Four steps ->

1. Environment variables for your account -->
   It should have a variable named "PYTHONPATH" with value like "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v5\python\Lib\site-packages"
2. Create a folder named "pgadmin" at "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin
   4\v5\python\Lib\site-packages" location
3. Copy-Paste all contents
   of "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v5\web\pgadmin" to "pgadmin" folder
   created in step-2
4. Copy-Paste -> i) migrations sub-folder,
   ii) config.py,
   iii) config_distro.py -- These three from
   "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin4\v5\web" to
   "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin4\v5\python\Lib\site-packages"

After above steps successful completion

- Open the new command prompt
- cd "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v5"

And you are ready to execute below command without more issues :)

```
python\python.exe web\setup.py --dump-servers C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\pgadmin_connections.json
```

By following above useful information, I solved below errors one after another on Windows10 : -

**Error 1 (Initial error) ->**
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v5\web\setup.py", line 13, in 
from pgadmin.model import db, User, Version, ServerGroup, Server, 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pgadmin'

**Error 2 ->**
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v5\web\setup.py", line 13, in 
from pgadmin.model import db, User, Version, ServerGroup, Server, 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pgadmin.model'

**Error 3 ->**
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v5\web\setup.py", line 15, in 
from pgadmin import create_app
ImportError: cannot import name 'create_app' from 'pgadmin' (unknown location)

**Error 4 ->**
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v5\web\setup.py", line 13, in 
from pgadmin.model import db, User, Version, ServerGroup, Server, 
File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v5\python\lib\site-packages\pgadmin_*init*_.py", line 36, in 
from pgadmin.utils import PgAdminModule, driver, KeyManager
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pgadmin.utils'

**Error 5 ->**
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v5\web\setup.py", line 13, in 
from pgadmin.model import db, User, Version, ServerGroup, Server, 
File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v5\python\lib\site-packages\pgadmin_*init*_.py", line 38, in 
from pgadmin.utils.session import create_session_interface, pga_unauthorised
File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v5\python\lib\site-packages\pgadmin\utils\session.py", line 26, in 
import config
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'

**Error 6 ->**
Error: Path doesn't exist: 'C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v5\python\Lib\site-packages\migrations'.  Please use the 'init' command to create a new scripts folder.