# How to create a Postgres instance

Tags: postgresql, installation

How do I create a (new) Postgres instance on Windows

Something along the lines:
`C:\postgresql\psql --create-server -name=MyAwesomeServer -host=localhost, etc.etc.`

I want to specify everything needed to create an instance on the command line rather than using a gui. That way I can port all/most of it to a different platform.

Comment: Different platforms have different ways to do this. The Debian/Ubuntu packages for Postgres have `pg_createcluster` which as far as I can tell is not available on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows 10 using [initdb](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-initdb.html)  and [pg_ctl](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-ctl.html)

```
mkdir C:\MyAwesomeDB 
C:\PostgreSQL\13\bin\initdb -U MyAwesomeUserID -W -D C:\MyAwesomeDB 

C:\PostgreSQL\13\bin\pg_ctl.exe -D C:\MyAwesomeDB -l logfile start
C:\PostgreSQL\13\bin\pg_ctl.exe stop -D C:\MyAwesomeDB
```

Answer (score 2):

That does not create an actual server.  It creates a record within pgadmin4 about how to connect to a server.  Yes, it is poorly named.  It should be called "create connection" or "configure connection" or something like that.

You create a server using initdb.exe, or using pg_ctl.exe with the 'initdb' action.  (The installer you use to install the software may have created a server for you automatically).

Comment: do you have an example of "initdb.exe, or using pg_ctl.exe" on the command line w/ example params?

Answer (score 1):

pgAdmin 4 stores Connection settings in a SqlLite database.
See [this DBA StackExchange posting](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53634/save-export-pgadmin-server-list-configuration-settings).

pgAdmin 3 on Windows *used* to store them in the Windows Registry.